# iterating through multiple radio buttons

Tags: radio-button

In C# WinForms I have several radio buttons, and in my code it looks like this:

```
public void Adjust_id()
{
    if (radio_button_0.Checked)
        (database.Record).active_id = 0;
    else if (radio_button_1.Checked)
        (database.Record).active_id = 1;
    else if (radio_button_2.Checked)
        (database.Record).active_id = 2;
    else if (radio_button_3.Checked)
        (database.Record).active_id = 3;
    else if (radio_button_4.Checked)
        (database.Record).active_id = 4;
    else if (radio_button_5.Checked)
        (database.Record).active_id = 5;
    else if (radio_button_6.Checked)
        (database.Record).active_id = 6;
    else if (radio_button_7.Checked)
        (database.Record).active_id = 7;
    else if (radio_button_8.Checked)
        (database.Record).active_id = 8;
    else if (radio_button_9.Checked)
        (database.Record).active_id = 9;
    else if (radio_button_A.Checked)
        (database.Record).active_id = 10;
    else if (radio_button_B.Checked)
        (database.Record).active_id = 11;
    else if (radio_button_C.Checked)
        (database.Record).active_id = 12;
    else if (radio_button_D.Checked)
        (database.Record).active_id = 13;
    else if (radio_button_E.Checked)
        (database.Record).active_id = 14;
    else if (radio_button_F.Checked)
        (database.Record).active_id = 15;
}
```

It's quite ugly in my opinion. Is there a better approach to shorten this code? I don't know how I could iterate through those radio buttons...

Comment: What language is this? You will need to provide a bit more detail or else the question will be flagged, deleted and stricken from the record..

Comment: I forgot to mention. I'm using WinForms with C#.

Comment: Sorry...never used C#. Does C# have the notion of a radio button group? Maybe you can find out the value based on that? Grasping at straws..I know..sorry.

Comment: All of those radio buttons probably have the same name.  Meaning, the "name" attribute of the radio button tag.  Radio buttons are supposed to be exclusive, so in order to only have 1 of those 16 buttons "checked" then they all should have the same name.  Look into Request["name"] where name is the name of all of your radio buttons.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add, then as long as you have the "value" attribute of each radiobutton set, you will know what the (database.Record).active_id should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a case statement, but I don't think that is what you want.

Look at this.  I created the Radio Buttons to be Dynamic.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Dictionary<int, RadioButton> RadioButtons = new Dictionary<int,RadioButton>();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                int j = i * 30;
                CreateRadioButton(i, j);
            }
            CheckRadioButton(2);
        }


        public void CheckRadioButton(int active_id)
        {
            RadioButton singRB = RadioButtons[active_id];
            singRB.Checked = true;
        }

        public void CreateRadioButton(int name, int topAdd)
        {
            RadioButton RB = new RadioButton();
            RB.Left = 20;
            RB.Top = 30 + topAdd;
            RB.Width = 300;
            RB.Height = 30;
            RB.Text = String.Format("I am a Dynamic RadioButton {0}", name);
            RB.Name = String.Format("RadioButton{0}", name);
            RadioButtons.Add(name, RB);
            Controls.Add(RB);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The small problem is that my buttons weren't created dynamically but it's definitely helping and I should find a solution from this example.